# R row_number() results in only 1s

Tags: r, row-number

I want to produce a table where each patient has a row number in order of highest RDI to lowest RDI.

Sample Data, RDItable:

| SubjectID | RDI | SomeOtherCols |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1004 | 100 | x |
| 1004 | 100 | y |
| 1004 | 100 | z |
| 1002 | 99.5 | x |
| 1002 | 99.5 | y |
| 1002 | 99.5 | z |
| 1001 | 85.1 | x |
| 1001 | 85.1 | y |
| 1001 | 85.1 | z |
| 1003 | 100 | x |
| 1003 | 100 | y |
| 1003 | 100 | z |

Here is what had worked for me in the past with minor adjustments (by including the RDI column)

```
attempt1<- RDItable %>% 
 distinct(SubjectID, RDI) %>% 
 arrange(desc(RDI)) %>% 
 mutate(row_id = row_number(RDI))
```

but this results in:

| SubjectID | RDI | row_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1004 | 100 | 1 |
| 1003 | 100 | 1 |
| 1002 | 99.5 | 1 |
| 1001 | 85.1 | 1 |

and I want each row to contain a different value:

| SubjectID | RDI | row_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1004 | 100 | 1 |
| 1003 | 100 | 2 |
| 1002 | 99.5 | 3 |
| 1001 | 85.1 | 4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the data already had a `rowwise` attribute which makes the `row_number()` to return only 1 as there is only a single row per group.  We may need to `ungroup` if that is the case

```
library(dplyr)
RDItable %>%
   ungroup %>%
   distinct(SubjectID, RDI) %>%
    arrange(desc(RDI)) %>% 
    mutate(row_id = row_number())
```

-output

```
  SubjectID   RDI row_id
1      1004 100.0      1
2      1003 100.0      2
3      1002  99.5      3
4      1001  85.1      4
```

---

The output can be replicated with `rowwise` attribute

```
> RDItable %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    distinct(SubjectID, RDI) %>%
    arrange(desc(RDI)) %>%
    mutate(row_id = row_number())
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Rowwise: 
  SubjectID   RDI row_id
      <int> <dbl>  <int>
1      1004 100        1
2      1003 100        1
3      1002  99.5      1
4      1001  85.1      1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had assumed that because I removed my Row_Number column prior to running through this code would solve the issue and it hadn't. Your solution completely solved my question. Thank you so much.